# How to add coredata to Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, core-data

I think the issue is with my for loop.
The count for the array is coming out to 0. No values are being added.

The NSLog does outup different info each time, but data is not being added to the mutable array.

NSLog:

> 2015-08-02 11:27:44.326 iOSInterviewPro[46661:1548947] Where can you
>   test Apple iPhone apps if you don’t have the device?
>
> 2015-08-02 11:27:44.326 iOSInterviewPro[46661:1548947] Which API is
>   used to write test scripts that help in exercising the application’s
>   user interface elements?

```
-(void) getQuiz {
 CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack coreDataStack];
// Fetching
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Jsonp"];

// Add Sort Descriptor
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"questions" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

// Execute Fetch Request
NSError *error = nil;
 NSArray *arr = [[coreDataStack managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (!error) {
    for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in arr) {
//            [questionsFArray addObject:[managedObject valueForKey:@"questions"]];
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", [managedObject valueForKey:@"questions"]);
        [questionsFArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [managedObject valueForKey:@"questions"]]];


    }

} else {
    NSLog(@"Error fetching data.");
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
}

NSLog(@"Count : %lu", (unsigned long)questionsFArray.count  );

}
```

Comment: Do you initialize `questionsFArray` anywhere? It might be `nil`.

Comment: omg I love you!  Totally forgot to do that!.